# Use multiple fonts in a single line with sifr3

Tags: javascript, flash, fonts, sifr

I am using sifr3 and I know it is supposed to let you use multiple fonts in one line.

I have tried a number of changes with my sifr.css and sifr_config.js files to no avail. I tried using spans, sub class of h1, etc.

Sample Link: http://www.liquidcomma.com/about_us/pages/overview/

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way of doing this. Save each font you want to use in a seperate file. Then don't use h1 or any tag you are already using with classes. Just set up brand new classes with custom name in your CSS and used them with the span tags.